# Recessed light holes

Tags: drywall, recessed-lighting

I cut recessed light holes in my ceilling. I was wondering if I can use anything to protect the rough inner edge of the cutout hole to protect drywall from chipping. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is a pretty jagged cut but for the most part, it doesn't matter because the light trim will cover it up and chipping won't occur that far out. Try using a hack saw blade with 32 teeth per inch. You'll get a smoother cut. I use one with a handle similar to the one shown below. You can also get a hole saw but they're not cheap if you're only doing a few holes. If you're a real fanatic for smoothness, you can coat the inside edge with some drywall mud.

[image]

(Picture from Walmart.om)